# could not write to hash-join temporary file: No space left on device

Tags: performance, postgresql, space, tablespace

I am executing PostgreSQL functions to update a table which has a huge amount of data and the update happens for about 100000 records everyday. During the update I get an error saying:

```
"could not write to hash-join temporary file: No space left on device"
```

I have not really been able to get something useful to overcome this error. I got something where it says to SET a temporary table spaces. But I was not able to find how do I create a temporary table space where the data will be stored during the executing of the update procedure.

Comment: Is the disk space where your PostgreSQL data located is running out of space ?

Comment: No, the disk has lot of space available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. `SQL> create tablespace temp_tbs location '/some/big/disk';`
2. change `temp_tablespaces = 'temp_tbs'` in postgresql.conf.
3. `select pg_reload_conf();`
4. enjoy

Comment: `SET temp_tablespaces  = temp_tbs;` can be also used

Comment: How can we know that the function being executed will use this particular temp tablespaces?

Comment: @YousufSultan it uses any of mentioned in temp_tablespaces... so if you specify severeal within a comma, it uses any of those in order you provided. If you specify only one - it uses it, if none set, it uses pg_default

Comment: Is there is another way because i don't have permission to postgres configuration as well as unable to create temp table space ?

Comment: no - If you have no permissions to use your big disk, you can't use it...

Comment: after `1` I get: `directory "/pg" does not exist`, but I have `drwxr-xr-x   2 postgres postgres  4096 Jul  6 22:04 pg` at root. Why this error happen?

Comment: I'm about 90% sure that using `SET temp_tablespaces` will only last for your session.

Comment: Big omission here. You have to run this too: `grant create on tablespace temp_space to public;`. Otherwise only the `postgres` user can use the tablespace.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue, but I was working with docker.

Just in case if you are working with docker too, go to:

`Docker Preferences` > `Disk Panel` > `Disk image size` and increase it.

It solved my problem.